# When was the first word "Kafir" / "Kuffar" reveal in the quran? and which surah?

Tags: quran, revelation, kuffar, order-of-revelation

I'm currently curious about the word Kafir in the Quran,
I read from http://quran.com/19/37. And then I’m starting to think, which was the first ayah reveal in the Quran talking about "Kafir"? According to timeline revelation.

Please answer with based on Hadiths or other reference.
Thank you

Comment: I found: _those who disbelieve_ in verse [68.51](http://quranx.com/Analysis/68.51) and it is [the second in chronological order of revelation](http://www.bombaxo.com/chronsurs.html).

Comment: thank you for finding the word. but you should add this to Answer Section.

Comment: both are allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is more likely to be an assumption, as I'm neither a specialist in the Order of tanzil nor could I find a specific Question on the topic so far. But I could find some links giving a certain order of tanzil (revelation) with complete Suwar/Surahs. AFAIK this order may differ when it comes to Verses, so maybe a Verse of Surah A has been revealed before another Verse from Surah B (which might be revealed or completed later then A) or A itself. So I think it's hard to tell whether the following is correct:

Assuming the Order of the Suwar/Surahs of the Qur'an on the pages I linked is correct, and also assuming that the Suwar have been revealed completely before each other I would say the most first appearance of this word would be in Surat al-Qalam  ([68:51](http://legacy.quran.com/68/51)), where the verb (disbelieve) appears and which most Scholars agree that it's the 2nd Surah which has been revealed. Then comes be Surat al-Muddathir ([74:10](http://legacy.quran.com/74/10)) where the noun (disbelievers) appears! Surat al-Muddathir is considered the 4th in the revelation order.

Here are two links [1](http://www.yabeyrouth.com/pages/index929.htm) & [2](http://www.hodaalquran.com/details.php?id=1354) about the order of revelation of the Suwar (only in Arabic so far)

And Allah knows best!